# Demystifying definition of the Random Variable

Tags: random-variables, definition

The intro on [Random Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) says that it is **a variable** (in bold), whose value depends on a chance. IMO, it sounds like a random value generator, whose value depends on a chance, just as random variable does. What is more dismaying is that [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is absolutely different. It says that random variable X is a mapping, $$X: \Omega \to E$$

That is, I see two problems in the basic introduction:

1. Why do you insist that it is a variable if it is more like random value generator or, formally, a function, [which is not a variable and not random](https://www.google.ee/search?q=%22random%20variable%20is%20not%20random%22) at all and
2. How do you reconcile two definitions of the random variable: informal, which displays the RV as a random generator, and formal, which says about probability space to a measurable space mapping.

Comment: Nothing is a variable.

Comment: A random variable is a function which takes a definite value on any point $\omega\in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the space  of elementary events. But it is "chance", or "fate", that chooses the point $\omega\in\Omega$ where $f$ is evaluated. Only in this way $f$ becomes "random".

Answer (score 3):

Consider a familiar example: Let $\Omega$ be the set of all outcomes of the toss of two dice:
$$
\Omega = \left\{ \begin{array}{cccccc} 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 \\ 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 \\
51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 \\ 61 & 62 & 63 & 64 & 65 & 66 \end{array}  \right\}
$$
Let $X: \Omega \to \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ be defined by $X=$ the sum of the two numbers, so that, for example, if the member of $\Omega$ above is $53$ then $X=5+3=8$.

Each subset of $\Omega$ is assigned a probability by assigning to each one-element subset the probability $1/36$.  That way we have
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=5) & = 4/36 \\
\Pr(X=6) & = 5/36 \\
\Pr(X=7) & = 6/36 \\
\Pr(X=8) & = 5/36 \\
\Pr(X=9) & = 4/36 \\
\Pr(X=10) & = 3/36 \\
& \qquad \text{etc.}
\end{align}

The idea is that the "outcome" is one member of $\Omega$ chosen randomly, and the value of the random variable is determined by the outcome.  More than one random variable can be defined on the space $\Omega$; for example, let $Y:\Omega\to\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the maximum of the two numbers, so that we would have
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y=6) & = 11/36 \\
\Pr(Y=5) & = 9/36 \\
\Pr(Y=4) & = 7/36 \\
& \qquad \text{etc.}
\end{align}

Another example would be this:

> $\Omega = $ the set of all voters in a state.
>
> $X(\omega) =$ the income of the voter named $\omega$
>
> $Y(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\omega$ votes “yes'' in the referendum}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$

If one voter $\omega\in\Omega$ is randomly chosen, then $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.  If $E\subseteq\Omega$ is the set of voters whose incomes are more than $\$1{,}000{,}000$ per year, then $\Pr(E)$ is the probability that the chosen voter $\omega$ is in the set $E$, i.e. that the chosen voter has an income more than $\$1{,}000{,}000$ per year.

Comment: Thanks. This is the best explanation of Random Variable as a function on sample space. You basically say what it means. I see now that it means that you map a sample space of pairs in the matrix to the sample space of 2-dice sums. But, I do not see which one of the answers you answer. I do not know if it is appropriate remark but Richard Feynman once stayed that people answer what they know rather than what they are asked, [like biologists](https://www.google.ee/search?q=All+living+creatures,+both+plant+and+animal,+are+made+of+little+brick-like+objects+called+%27cells%27).

Comment: Maybe you need to be clearer about what is asked.  If you're applying a random number generator to the first space above, you're just throwing two dice --- that's the random number generator. Likewise your method of picking a voter at random is your random number generator. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The, you should ask for clarification or explain what is wrong in my question. Unless you don't do that, we won't achieve any progress. First answer from Ant helped to undersand that $\Omega$ stands for the randomness/random generator. I wonder why do you define the RV as random generator $\Omega$ informally and then formally define it as a simple function from $\Omega$ to something else. I think it should also be clear in my question. How can I make people addressing my question rather than familiar keyword in the title?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov : "I wonder why do you define the RV as random generator $\Omega$ informally and then formally define it as a simple function from $\Omega$ to something else." Because the randomness is expressed by the probability measure on $\Omega$ rather than by anything about the function $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you for starting to answer my question finally. You basically say that the informal definition is the right one whereas the formal one defines something different, and, therefore, you say, two definitions define the same thing. Sorry, but I still consider it as nonsense. You simply reproduce the things that I see absurd rather than resolve the contradiction.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov : I'm not really aware of two different definitions involved in anything done above. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is nothing random in the definition.

The point is that you can think of $\Omega$ as "states of the world": you don't know what is going to happen in the future, what $\omega$ is going to "materialise", so to speak.

So you don't know which values $X$ is going to take; but $X$ gives you a way to "translate" events from the real world (like "the dice will come up $6$) to a more "mathematical" object (usually $\mathbb R$)

Of course since $\omega$ is "random", so is $X(\omega)$.

In general though every measurable function is (by definition) a random variable (also a function like $f(x)=x-2$ if you take $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and the usual Borel sigma algebra) so there is no real difference, we just use this term in probability theory.

Another point is that we usually "forget" about $\Omega$. That is we say something like : Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable... We do not specify $\Omega$, we don't know which kind of relation $X$ induces on the elements of $\Omega$; so what happens is that $X$ is basically "random", is the only random thing there is in our setting.

Comment: You say that if your automobile can carry various people, it is a various automobile!

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov ehm.. what? I did not understand that :-P

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov I added another small paragraph, maybe it's more clear

Comment: I was saying that you say that function $\Omega \to R$ is random because you supply random input to it. Now, with your last edit, where you say that we abstract the function away and are left with source of randomness only, the random generator $\Omega$, we arrived at the the informal definition of the RV. This makes perfect sense now. It was not obvious to me that the random generator $\Omega$ is built-in into the function.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov Glad I could help but wait, $\Omega$ is not "built in", is that we don't specify it, because usually we don't care about it. For example we want to fine the expected value of $X$; as long as we know the distribution of $X$, we can do it, we do not care about $\Omega$. It is not built in but it is not specified a lot of the times.

Comment: Then I do not see any connection of $\Omega \to R$ to the random generator. If you say that random input turns your function into a random variable then sine function is a random variable rather than a pure function. I see no point to calling a pure function a `random variable`, once you say that it is not hardly connected to a random source.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov the sine **is** a random variable, as per definition. The difference is that we *think* of $\Omega$ as "random stuff from the real world", but as I have already said this needs not to be the case. Again, a random variable is just a measurable function, so fixating on the definition will not help your intuition. If you recognize that we think of $\Omega$ as random, and that usually we don't specify $\Omega$ so that all it's left "random" is $X$, that you can understand why this name. You seem to be after some compelling reason.It's not there. Is just useful, helps intuition.

Comment: Sine is a random variable? I am asking what is the point of stating such nonsense. Why do you call it a random variable? You should understand that it is normal to call the [functions of random variable](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/128) but why do you insist that function of random variable = random variable?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov Again, there is no compelling reason. In the end is because people find it useful. I tried to describe more or less why, but I can't "prove" that it is the right name. It's just a name. If you want to start your own movement and call random variables "functions of random variable" go ahead :-)

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov what's a random function?

Comment: Do you mean that function of random variable is not a random variable?

Comment: @ValentinaTihomirov if $f$ is measurable (hence a random variable ) and $X$ is a random variable, then also $f(X)$ is measurable (hence a random variable )